# Why does an interpolated array in a regexp return a position instead of nil?

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, interpolation

Here's what I tried

```
lorem = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co'
# => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co"
oops  = ['oops']
# => ["oops"]
```

Here is what I got:

```
lorem =~ /#{oops}/
# => 1
```

I would have expected nil or an exception.

Apparently it is taking the first item in the string array for oops and matching that. 'o' is the second character in 'Lorem ipsum...'

I'm using Ruby 2.3.3 in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedding an array in a regular expression is possible, however you can't directly use interpolation. As you found out, directly interpolating it results in a [character class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) that will match all characters in the elements plus double-quotes and commas.

Instead use:

```
ary = ['a']
regex = Regexp.union(ary) # => /a/
/#{regex.source}/ # => /a/

ary = ['a', 'b']
regex = Regexp.union(ary) # => /a|b/
/#{regex.source}/ # => /a|b/
```

You can read more about [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#method-c-union) and [`source`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#method-i-source) in the documentation.

But wait! There's more!

Normally you want to group that sub-expression to avoid suddenly generating substring false-positive hits:

```
/foo#{regex.source}/ # => /fooa|b/
```

which, because regex engines are greedy, would match `fooa` or `b`:

```
'fooa'[/foo#{regex.source}/] # => "fooa"
'foob'[/foo#{regex.source}/] # => "b"
```

Instead this'll help:

```
/foo(?:#{regex.source})/ # => /foo(?:a|b)/

'fooa'[/foo(?:#{regex.source})/] # => "fooa"
'foob'[/foo(?:#{regex.source})/] # => "foob"
```

But there's even more!

The embedded regular expression maintains its own set of [options](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options) that are preserved when interpolated, resulting in hard to debug problems if you aren't paying attention:

```
regex = Regexp.union(ary) # => /a|b/
/#{regex}/ # => /(?-mix:a|b)/
```

From the documentation:

> `i`, `m`, and `x` can also be applied on the subexpression level with the *(?on-off)* construct, which enables options *on*, and disables options *off* for the expression enclosed by the parentheses.

If the outer pattern uses a different option, say, for case-insensitive matches then something like this could happen:

```
regex = /FOO/
'foo'[/#{regex}/i] # => nil
```

You'd think that the `i` option on the outer expression would fix things but here's what's happening:

```
/#{regex}/i # => /(?-mix:FOO)/i
```

The simple fix is to use the `source` method like in the above examples which returns the text of the expression but not the settings of the options:

```
/#{regex.source}/i # => /FOO/i
'foo'[/#{regex.source}/i] # => "foo"
```

Using `source` isn't always the correct thing to do, but it helps a lot until you're sure there's a case where you deliberately want to use an embedded expressions *with* a different set of options. If you do get to that point be sure to comment the code well at that point so your future you, or anyone else inheriting the code, will understand what's happening. Otherwise it can take days to figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it:

```
irb(main):008:0> /#{oops}/
=> /["oops"]/
```

The regex evaluates to a pattern that is going to look for one of the characters in the brackets and match on the first one it runs into, i.e., the 'o' in the second position in 'Lorem ipsum . . .'

Have I found it?

Comment: To expand further, interpolating (inside strings or regexes) just calls `#to_s` on the object being interpolated and uses that. Yes, this is the correct answer.

Comment: You found it but you didn't find the fix to it. Answers are not only supposed to point to the problem, they're also supposed to provide the fix and explain it.